# How to mount a samba share on the same machine?

Tags: debian, samba

On plain Debian Jessie, I am trying to create a samba share to test an application of mine.

I installed samba 4.2.10. I create a new share in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` that has the following share:

```
[public]
comment = public
path = /home/public
read only = no
guest ok = yes
browseable = yes
writeable = yes
public = yes
```

When I try to mount it using the following command:

```
mount //10.1.0.38/public /mnt -o guest
```

It fails with:

```
Unable to find suitable address.
```

When I check dmesg I have the following error:

```
[169628.801413] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[169628.801581] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -111
```

Trying to mount the share in an lxc with its own ip fails too.

By the way, I configured on network bridge on my machine. I can mount samba shares from other machines.